# Setting 3 images to one CSS rollover effect?

Tags: css

Hi I'm using the css rollover code to change out a hyperlink image, but now I need to change another set of image. User hovers over Fun Facts and the menu button changes but I have another image below the menu that I would like to change as well. Do I have to do a div show/hide for the second sent of images or can I tie two images into a hover css effect to change?

Comment: You have to use JavaScript to do that. I'd recommend JQuery.

Comment: i was trying to stay clear of jquery / jscript, i wanted to keep the site coding light

Comment: @Nightfirecat @SirB - Obviously you would beat me at Jeopardy

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're doing is similar to this?
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

one for `a:link`, `a:visited` and another for `a:hover`

Comment: I need either a way to have a dual hover so the effect changes the menu image and the image at the bottom of the menu box

Comment: You might need jQuery to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSS Sprite to change the images.  Low system impact, works without JavaScript.  Here are a few references:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: i'm using a png sprite image for the menu images. I just have another image I want to incorporate. When the user hovers over Fun Fact! i want a picture of a health chart to appear at the bottom of the menu box.

Comment: You haven't given us a link to the site, but why not make the hover state image partially transparent.  The top would be the button image, then a blank space then the picture that you want to display at the bottom of the box.  You may need to play with the z-index to make sure that the picture displays properly.